# Regex on negative assertions for specific strings

Tags: regex, jsr330

What is the regex using javax.validation.constraints @Pattern for user not to be able to choose username such as **"admin" or "manager"**?

I am not understanding how to use "?!" to indicate word which must be excluded. Could you please suggest some examples with exclusion of just "admin" string and I will figure out the rest.

Comment: Okay, everything except the first paragraph of this question is just a rant. -1, and closevote, until you make this an actual question.

Comment: I'm not helping when your "question" is just a rant.

Comment: You're not going to get very much help if your "question" includes a rant about being sad if we mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: If you don't edit your question into something sensible, nobody will help you. We're not going to "answer" a non-question. This is not the place to rant about things you don't like.

Comment: Better, but you still need to show at least a little research effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression which will match any value that is not `manager` or `admin`:

```
^(?!(admin|manager)).*$
```

and if you want to disallow the user to choose usernames which contain `manager` or `admin` anywhere in the string like `usr_admin`, `myManager_101`, etc ..

Then you can use the following:

```
^(?!.*?(admin|manager)).*$
```

Comment: absolutely great, simple to understand, saved for history and future use. Could not crack the other questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Aubergine You are welcome. I voted to close your question at first but then you made your self more clear. Anyway, don't forget to make the expression case-incentive so that it works for `manager`, `MaNager`, `AdMiN`, etc..

Comment: I think you forgot to anchor the lookahead in your first regex.  As it is, you're only matching strings that don't *start* with `admin` or `manager`.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thank you. That is exactly what I want the first expression to do.